# I put it far away

Tags: grammar

He put the remote control far away from me.

> "I put it far away."
>
> "I put it far."

He told me.

Does the second sentence grammatically correct if remove away from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Far away" often implies a considerable distance, so if you put it on the other side of the room that wouldn't really qualify.

> Downtown is **far away** from my house.

However, distance can be relative and "far away" can be close by, just much *farther away* than something else.

> Make sure to put the microphone **far away** from the big speakers, or you're going to get feedback.

Of course, you might be having fun with the person.

> A: Where is my phone?
>   B: I took it and hid it **far away**.
>   A: Really?
>   B: No, I'm just kidding.  It's right there on the table.

If you just want to say it's some distance but still visible, you can say "over there".

> I put the TV remote **over there** because our son wouldn't stop changing the channel.